# Freeze (pause) an Xorg output

Tags: xorg

Is there a functionality to freeze or pause a single output and have it show the same picture until I unfreeze it?

While using my notebook for presentations I often run into cheaper and older beamers that do not offer a "Freeze" functionality. When doing hands-on presentation, it often is desirable to prepare something without showing it to the beamer and the viewership just yet.